# Loop back to first image in a light box after reaching the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that uses a light box for the galleries and I just added arrows in so you can scroll from left to right. How to i make it loop back to the first picture when it reaches the end?

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p></p>");

//An image to overlay
$overlay.append($image);

var $leftArrow = $("<div id='leftArrow'></div>");
var $rightArrow = $("<div id='rightArrow'></div>");
var $closeLightbox = $("<div id='closeLightbox'></div><div    style='clear:both'></div>");

$image.before($closeLightbox);
$image.before($leftArrow);
$image.after($rightArrow);

//A caption to overlay
$overlay.append($caption);

//Add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);

//Capture the click event on a link to an image
$("#boxCabinet a,#channelLetters a, #customSignage a, #postandpanel a    ").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

getCurrentImage(this);

//Show the overlay.
$overlay.show();
});

$leftArrow.click(function(){
getPrevImage();
});

$rightArrow.click(function(){
getNextImage();
 });

 function getCurrentImage (currentImage) {  
thisImage = currentImage;
var imageLocation = $(currentImage).attr("href");
//Update overlay with the image linked in the link
$image.attr("src", imageLocation);

var captionText = $(currentImage).children("img").attr("alt");
//Get child's alt attribute and set caption
$caption.text(captionText);
}

function getPrevImage() {
imageParent = $(thisImage).parent().prev();
if(imageParent.length!=0){
  thisImage = $(imageParent).children("a");
// imageLocation = $(thisImage).attr("href");
// $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
}
getCurrentImage(thisImage);

}

function getNextImage() {
imageParent = $(thisImage).parent().next();
if(imageParent.length!=0){
thisImage = $(imageParent).children("a");
  // imageLocation = $(thisImage).attr("href");
  // $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
}
getCurrentImage(thisImage);
}

//When overlay is clicked
$closeLightbox.click(function(){
//Hide the overlay
$overlay.hide();
});
```

and heres sample of the html

```
   <div id="portfolio">
   <a name="boxCabinet"></a>
   <h1>Box Cabinet </h1>

    <ul id="boxCabinet">

    <% csv.each do |row|%>
    <%   if row[3] == "Box" && row[2] == "Active" %>
    <li><a href="<%= row[0]%>"><img src=<%= row[0]%> width="120" height="120"alt=<%=row[1]%>></a></li>

       <% end %>
       <% end %>

    </ul>

   <a name="channelLetters"></a> 
  <h1>Channel Letters </h1>
   <ul id="channelLetters">
<% csv.each do |row|%>
    <%   if row[3] == "Channel" && row[2] == "Active"%>
        <li><a href="<%= row[0]%>"><img src=<%= row[0] %> width="120"    height="120"alt="<%=row[1]%>"></a></li>

    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or codePen.

Comment: You are asking about client-side control. As such, the (Ruby) code that you use on the server to generate your HTML is not relevant. Please edit your "html" to be the actual HTML produced (hint: view source on the browser). And, as @IvanModric suggests, you are far more likely to get help if you create a self-contained, working, **pared-down** example of your problem.

Comment: @Phrogz  here's a link to a pen i just made. Don't know how to add images to it so the arrows don't show up next to the pictures but if you click next to them the will scroll http://codepen.io/josephmckenzie/pen/ZWzvQN